# Beamer, customize the headline create an extra blank line on top

Tags: beamer, header-footer, headline

I try to use customize `headline` of `footline` of `Warsaw` theme. MWE as the following

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{microtype}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usecolortheme{crane}
\useoutertheme{split}
\usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}
      \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\color{white}{}\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}
      \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\color{white}{Headline}\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}
      \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\color{white}{}\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}
      \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\color{white}{Footline}\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}
    \section{The First Section}
        \subsection{The First Subsection}
            \begin{frame}[t]{}
                \frametitle{Hello World}
            \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The generated page is as the following
[image]

As can be seen, the footline is OK. However for headline, there is an extra white line on top of the page.

What is the difference between `headline` and `footline` causing this?

==== New findings =====

Find that add a `%` between 2 `beamercolorbox` will resolve the issue

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex, leftskip=2ex,rightskip=2ex]{section in head/foot}
      \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\color{white}{}\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}% <-add this "%" will resolve the issue
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex, leftskip=2ex,rightskip=2ex]{subsection in head/foot}
      \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\color{white}{Headline}\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Looks like a in line comment makes the difference. Not sure what is the root cause.

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer

Comment: Edit and remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new line becomes a space.

Your `%` simply makes TeX ignore the newline character and therefore ignore a space between the first two heading boxes (50% left, 50% right stuff). Because TeX breaks at glue (spaces have glue) automatically in horizontal mode (explicitly caused by `\leavevmode`), removing spaces forces all onto the same line. You might notice that the implicit space exists in both the header and footer lines (see the white space).

I am pretty sure that is what is going on.

As far answering the different behaviors by headline and footline

> What is the difference between headline and footline causing this?

Finding the answer requires a painful search through the source code of beamer and how frames are built. If I find the reason, I will add it here.

Here is a simple document that repeats the letter "a" under two different conditions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcount\step%init

\step=0
\loop
a
\ifnum\step<100
\advance\step by 1
\repeat

\step=0
\loop
a% <- cancel out the implicit space caused by the new line here
\ifnum\step<100
\advance\step by 1
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. The footline also has problem if don't add the `%`, it just don't show up because the added line is on top of it and we don't notice that until some content is added near it.